# What is the benefit of making heavy initialization of a property static in php?

Tags: php, oop, properties, initialization

When I define an array property with a default value:

```
class Foo {
    protected $leArray = [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'baz',
    ];
}
```

my IDE, phpstorm, warns me due to code inspection that:

> This property initializatioin seems to be quite 'heavy', probably it should be defined as static.

Yet why should it? What is the benefit to make such an initialization static?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's unrelated to PHP even when you ask for the particular case in PHP.

Your IDE warns you because maybe this property containing an array may be not modified during the life-time of the class instance. Thus, you don't want to instantiate the whole class with a new array everytime. That is, you could turn the so-called property into a *static property* and avoid many instances of same array and share one to all `Foo` class instances.

BTW, if such array will be modified during the life-time of a given `Foo` instance, you don't want this property to be `static`, unless you want that one instance could modify it for all  other instances in a moment in time.